# How could I know mongo data unused space

Tags: mongodb

In Mongo, the storage size is pre-allocated, example, the db.stats() output as below, the storageSize : 65536 is not full used by the mongo document, but how could I know the free space is available for the pre-allocated storageSize?

"127.0.0.1:27018" : {
         "db" : "test",
         "collections" : 1,
         "objects" : 10,
         "avgObjSize" : 53.08618233618234,
         "dataSize" : 530,
         "storageSize" : 65536,
         "numExtents" : 0,
         "indexes" : 1,
         "indexSize" : 532,
         "ok" : 1

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the answer should be equal to storageSize - dataSize?

This document can be really helpfull : http://blog.mongolab.com/2014/01/how-big-is-your-mongodb/

And the db.stats() document of mongodb: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/dbStats/, where you can find the meaning of every values returned by dbStats

Comment: You are correct if the Mongo Storage Engine use non-compression model. If use the wiredTiger mongo storage engine, the default behavior will be compression, which means that the dataSize is greater than storageSize, how to solve in this scenario?

Comment: There were some lack of information in your first question actually.
I guess that you have at least mongo 3.0 and configured wiredTiger because your db.stats() does not return some information about mmapv1 engine.

Actually, if dataSize is compressed by the engine, you have the compressed value returned by db.stats(). You said that dataSize is greater than storageSize, it's not true. It's eventually possible that uncompressed dataSize might be bigger than your storageSize. But it won't happen in your database, since you are using the wiredTiger enginge, so what's the real question?